# PowerShell unable to remove space between text and String

Tags: string, powershell

In PowerShell I am trying to find a way to remove the text from an output of text and a String.

```
Write-Host 'File located at C:\'$Fileline.FilePath -
```

I get an output of

```
c:\ program files\path
```

The space between c:\ and "Program files" is what I want to remove.  Do I have to convert the text to a string, and then output it as two strings and then remove the spaces?

Comment: `Write-Host "File located at C:\$($Fileline.FilePath)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you are passing multiple strings to `Write-Host`, which it is then joining with spaces. This behaviour is somewhat unique to `Write-Host`.

You can meet your need by sending a single double quoted string to `Write-Host`, which you can then put your variable inside and it will be expanded. However because you are accessing a property of your variable, you need to wrap it in a sub-expression: `$()`:

```
Write-Host "file located at C:\$($Fileline.FilePath) -"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, but why did you include the  `space -` at the end of the line?

Comment: I was just mirroring what was in your original code, but if the " -" part shouldn't be there then just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the PowerShell `-f` formatting operator:

```
Write-Host ("File located at C:\{0} -" -f $FileLine.FilePath)
```

There's good info on `-f` at [SS64](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) and at [TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.powershell-using-the-f-format-operator.aspx)

Comment: This did not work for me.  It appears that the -f is assumed to be the start of "-foregroundcolor" option.  it gave the following message `Write-Host : Cannot bind parameter 'ForegroundColor'. `

Comment: This would work as it would make `-f` operate on the string as Jeff intended vs being treated like a parameter of Write-Host: `Write-Host ("File located at C:\{0} -" -f $FileLine.FilePath)`

Comment: Hmmm... I've never seen that happen, but you can force the correct interpretation with `Write-Host ("File located at C:\{0} -" -f $FileLine.FilePath)`.

Comment: FWIW I _always_ have to use braces when I do this because of the parameter interpretation issues. It does make sense that you would have to in a normal environment.